# Spark Streaming finds file but claims it can't find the file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have the below - which monitors a directory & pulls in the logs every X seconds.

The issue I have is this:

- I set the script running
- I then create a file in the directory (let's say testfile.txt)
- The script then errors saying textfile.txt does not exist

It found the file and the filename, so it does exist and it finds it.

What I can see is that I define the path with a `file:///` and it returns an error that it can't find `file:/`. So it seems to be missing two // for some reason:

Thanks for any help!!!!

**Code**

```
#only files after stream starts
df = spark_session\
    .readStream\
    .option('newFilesOnly', 'true')\
    .option('header', 'true')\
    .schema(myschema)\
    .text('file:///home/keenek1/analytics/logs/')\
    .withColumn("FileName", input_file_name())
```

**Error**

```
FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/keenek1/analytics/logs/loggywoggywoo.txt does not exist\
```

Comment: are you running this in local or cluster, if it cluster you can use hdfs:// instead of file://

Comment: is it working ??

Comment: It is @Srinivas - thank you! One other question if I may. If the same log file is overwritten lets say hourly, the checkpoint doesn't reprocess the file. I need it to say 'if modified time changes, reprocess' - is that possible?

Comment: which version of spark are you using ?

Comment: It;s Spark2 - thank you again for help

Comment: can you tell me your file is overwritten in hdfs , every time is correct ? & how frequent this file is going to update ?

Comment: I have checked spark source code & it is only looking for new file names not timestamp. so for your question it will not process once its processed file. for your reference please check this link - https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/5d673319af81bb826e5f532b5ff25f2d4b2da122/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/FileStreamSource.scala#L122

Comment: workaround will be, point your spark streaming to different directory & use spark listeners to check file timestamp from actual directory if any changes in file timestamp, move that file to your streaming directory with new name.. :)

Comment: Thanks! I can't mark it as an answer as its a comment :(

Comment: I have added our conversation as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change file:/// to hdfs://.

```
df = spark_session\
    .readStream\
    .option('newFilesOnly', 'true')\
    .option('header', 'true')\
    .schema(myschema)\
    .text('hdfs://home/keenek1/analytics/logs/')\ # changed file:/// to hdfs://
    .withColumn("FileName", input_file_name())
```

**For below question** 
If the same log file is overwritten lets say hourly, the checkpoint doesn't reprocess the file. I need it to say 'if modified time changes, reprocess' - is that possible?

**workaround** will be, point your spark streaming to different directory & use spark listeners to check file timestamp from actual directory if any changes in file timestamp, move that file to your streaming directory with new name

Let me know if you want code, I can give you in scala, may be you need to convert that into python.

Comment: Thanks - code would be so helpful. HDFS log file modified times are set as a job starts. So if the job takes 20 minutes, how do I know it's completed & I should move the file. Also, will Spark Streaming pick up a log file, if its modified time is 10 minutes earlier (when a job started)?

Comment: Good point.. Who is push files to hdfs .. do you have control in that ?

Comment: unfortunately not, they're just application logs that are running. I wonder if I could set a time delay - process the file 5 minutes after it arrives?

Comment: If you have timestamp column in your data, store max processed timestamp somewhere in hdfs & use that timestamp to process next data.